# Geometric Brownian motion with target skewness and kurtosis

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes, skewness, kurtosis

The Cholesky inversion method can be adopted to set a target **correlation** matrix when artificially generating a *multivariate* geometric Brownian motion dataset

Can the **moments** of a *univariate* GBM be targeted as well? (mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis)

If so, does this mean it is possible for a generated GBM to be non-normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) doesn't have skewness $0$ and kurtosis $3$.

The value (position) of a GBM process at time $t$ given its value at some earlier time (without loss of generality, I'll label that time $0$) has a lognormal distribution - not a normal distribution.

Specifically, the lognormal distribution has parameters $\mu t$ and $\sigma^2 t$.

The mean and variance of the position at time $t$ are a function of $t$ (and the drift and volatility parameters, $\mu$ and $\sigma$). The skewness and kurtosis will be a function of the $\sigma$ parameter (and indeed $t$ as well, as Sextus Empiricus points out in comments; the variance of the logs grows with $t$, so the distribution of the value at time $t$ becomes both more skew and more kurtotic as $t$ grows).

Comment: The skewness and kurtosis of the position at time $t$ will also be a function of $t$.

Comment: how to reconcile the fact that GBM doesn't have skewness or excess kurtosis, but skewness and kurtosis of a GBM grows with $t$?

Comment: What makes you think that GBM is not skew?